# Safari CSS rule vh-units?

Tags: html, css, safari, viewport-units

Does anybody know if there is a fix for Safari vh rule?

```
#what{
 min-height:70vh;
}
```

All working ok, in all browsers, but only in Safari it is not recognized?
Is there a fix for safari, that we can use VH rule in css?

Comment: safari 7.0 supports vh units. http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: This provides a fix for the repaint issue in Safari: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill

Comment: Safari 6.0+ supports vh and vw.
[see this link]https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Vw/Vh, use rem with this JavaScript. The "run code snippet" might create confusion, cause its window "resizes" by zooming. To test this, just copy this code into some html file and run it in Safari and other browsers (or see "Full Page").

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
(function (doc, win) {
        var docEl = doc.documentElement,
            recalc = function () {
                var clientWidth = docEl.clientWidth;
                if (!clientWidth) return;

                docEl.style.fontSize = clientWidth + 'px';
                docEl.style.display = "none";
                docEl.clientWidth; // Force relayout - important to new Android devices
                docEl.style.display = "";
            };
 
        // Abort if browser does not support addEventListener
        if (!doc.addEventListener) return;

        // Test rem support
        var div = doc.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 1rem');

        // Abort if browser does not recognize rem
        if (div.style.fontSize != "1rem") return;

        win.addEventListener('resize', recalc, false);
        doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', recalc, false);
    })(document, window);
</script>
<style>
    @charset "utf-8";
    *{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
    div {position:fixed;width:40%;height:30%;background-color:yellow;color:blue;font-size:0.02rem;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>in this case 0.01 rem == 1vw . You need to remove body margins.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

For more explenation, see this article that I ve found.
http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your code, you can use this trick:

in front of vh value use % or em, or pixels, so that the browsers that do not support it take the value:

```
.this{
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```